# Connecting QGIS 2.x to Firebird Database via ODBC?

Tags: qgis, connection, odbc

I tried to connect a Firebird Database in QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 via ODBC to a database and get following error message:

> Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for SYSDBA/masterkey@Akdees
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture
>   mismatch between the Driver and Application

**Funny, that it does work with QGIS 1.8!** but fails with QGIS 2.2 and 2.4. Does anyone have an idea as to what the reason is and how to make it work again?

Comment: Did u find the solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 1):

As Qgis 2.x is outdated, I post here the solution I found for QGIS 3.x on a Windows 10 64 bit.

**Prerequisite:**

- QGIS 3.x 32-bit installed (I used the 3.16.12 version),
- installation of the Firebird driver (see here => https://firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/). I installed the lastest version for the 64-bit,
- configuration of the ODBC Data Sources for Windows as follow:
  [image: Firebird ODBC Setup]

Do not forget to adapt the path for the Database and the Client fields.

The password by default for a firebird database is *masterkey*

**in QGIS 3.x (32-bit)**

Go to Layer>Add Layer>Add Vector Layer and select "Database" as the Source Type. Create a new connection and fill the configuration as follow:

- A name for the connection,
- The path to the folder containing the database,
- The Database name (must match the Data Source Name previously configured in the ODBC Data Sources).
  [image]

Check the connection with the "Test Connection" button.